# Multiplication of Dedekind cuts, W. Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[walter rudins book mathematical analysis, page no-19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNKI2.png)

here in this book the defination of the multiplication of two cuts is given as 
shown in image, But by this definition,
how can we prove the third condition of cut?

third condition is the cut has no largest number.

because here in definition given that

$p\leq rs$ .  and that follows that  $rs$  is largest element in the cut $\alpha \beta $. so what would we do for this.???

Comment: I guess you are missing half the definition.

Comment: No, $r$ and $s$ are varying, and none of them are maximal